# Is research prize from Italy taxable in the UK for a non-domicile resident?

Tags: fees

I feel it's a complicated wording question. I am an international student studying in the UK as a PhD student. I received a research prize from an Italian academic society for training purposes (I am needed to spend a month in Italy doing research). The prize is worth €3000 and subject to 30% Italian income taxation.

The coordinator from the society indicated that I could ask for a certificate of residence from the UK tax authority to avoid double taxation. I am still very perplexed about my situation.

1. Would I be taxed in the UK? (I am also a recipient of a PhD tax-free studentship)
2. Has anyone ever required the certificate from the HMRC? Can you please share your experience and the process? I am in Italy now so I am not sure what I could do.
3. If the Italian side deducts the taxation, will I be able to claim it back when I return to the UK?

   Thank you!

Comment: This is a question about tax laws, not academia...

Comment: Thank you. I posted in a hope that other researchers may be in the same situation and could offer their experience. Should I move it to the money subforum?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be a much better fit for Money.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about taxation, not academia.

Comment: Ring HMRC and ask them. Contrary to what you might expect from officials, they are very, very helpful to people who ask them for help. Their web site has the helpline numbers.